# Adding a set to a list of sets

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I'm having an issue with adding a set to a list of sets. The code builds fine but gives me a Null pointer exception whenever I run it, and I have no idea why. Here it is:

```
public class Jaccard{

List<SentenceUtils> sents;
List<Set> shingleSets;

public Jaccard( List<SentenceUtils> list ){

    sents = list;
    generateShingleSets();
}

private void generateShingleSets(){

    for(int i = 0; i < sents.size(); i++){

        String[] shingle = sents.get(i).getShingles();
        Set<String> setShingles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(shingle));


    }
    shingleSets.add(setShingles);
}
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: Add shingleSets=new ArrayList<Set>(); at the declaration.

Comment: Code you posted doesn't compile which means in current form it can't be run and throw any exception. Shouldn't your `shingleSets.add(setShingles);` be inside loop?

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I got it to work! I just needed to put in that part at the declaration and have the .add(setShingles) in the loop.